# interpretation needed for C

Tags: c

I am really new to the C language and recently asked for code help on stack overflow and a really great person gave me this code.

```
for(int m = 1; m < 262144; m <<= 1) putc("\n12345"[!!(96221 & m) + !!(26520 & m) + !!(18192 & m) + !!(1536 & m) + !!(1024 & m)], stdout);
```

Which prints out

```
1
123
12345
123
1
```

This was exactly what I was looking for.

However I do not know how this code works and also I have google’d these things above but I can not find/ understand it.

Especially with
‘
<<=, All those weird ginormous numbers.
‘
these two.

So, can someone explain how this code works? And explain what each part of the codes are?

Comment: Step 1: Change the decimal constants to hexadecimal to gain insight.

Comment: Just want to offer the perspective that writing unreadable, hard to understand code like that is arguably not "brilliant".

Comment: Being a genius and writing a brilliant code is great and all. But that does not mean that the code will be productive, in the sense that someone(the author included) **ever** will use it. I understand the irony of OP here, but I do not understand why he did post the code here, on SO. There are special web sites dedicated to such code. Why bother?

Comment: *and a really great person* That was clearly not meant to be really helpful. It probably was meant to demonstrate that asking for a turn-key solution is a terrible idea for learning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure the person who gave you this code was brilliant so much as devious... this looks like deliberately obfuscated code :)

```
m <<= 1
```

The above means "shift the bits in m left by one position", which has the effect of multiplying `m` by 2.

```
putc(..., stdout);
```

`putc(` is a function to print a single character to a file (in this case, to `stdout`)

```
"\n12345"[!!(96221 & m) + !!(26520 & m) + !!(18192 & m) + !!(1536 & m) + !!(1024 & m)]
```

This line computes the character to print.  `"\n12345"` is an array of characters to choose from, and then the text inside the [brackets] is computing an index (between 0 and 5) into that array; the character at that index will be the one that is printed.

The `!!` prefixes are double-applications of the boolean not-operator, used to convert the value in parentheses to 1 if it was non-zero and to 0 if it was zero.

The `(blah & m)` pieces are checking the given integer-constant to see if a particular bit is set in that constant, or not.  If the particular bit is set, 1 is added to the sum that will be used to calculate the index into the array.  I don't think I'm smart enough to give more details on why those particular numeric values were chosen :)

Comment: These magic numbers are bitpatterns that build the index of the character, Note them in binary and see that the sequence of sums gives 1, 0, 3, 2, 1, 0, and so on.